# how to add a page as my favorite in android?

Tags: android

I am working in a news application related project. In that project I want to add the selected page into my favorite list. It should use a preference concept. This is the requirement, but I don't know how to do this.. If anyone knows, Please help me

Comment: By "add the selected page" do you mean a web page address?

Comment: yes. I want add that page url in preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok..den you can simply create an Arraylist and save it to a file on the SDcard.each time you open the application  just open the file and retrive the list from it.
PS:sorry for replying late i was busy with some work.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use many ways

1. Using Shared Preferences
2. Using the Internal Storage
3. Using Databases

please read this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) it may help you

Comment: Thank you, I will surely go through this